# Clean up WordPress code that repeats

Tags: wp-query, customization

I want to use the following code multiple times in the same page template, however the template gets too big when it comes to lines of code and therefore size. Every time I use it I change only one parameter and 99% remains the same. The parameter I change is **`'terms'=>'pop'`**. I know I can display all posts and all taxonomy terms (taxonomies posts under each taxonomy) with a relatively small piece of code but that will not work as I want since I want to order taxonomies in a custom way, not by title or term (ASC/DSC). What I am thinking is maybe add the code to a fuction and each time I call the function I just pass the parameter which changes.

The code:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
                        'post_type'      => 'stations',
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'posts_per_page' => -1,
                        'orderby' => 'title',
                        'order' => 'ASC',
                        'tax_query' => array(
                                         array(
                                            'taxonomy' => 'genres',
                                            'field' => 'name',
                                            'terms' => 'pop' // THIS IS WHAT CHANGES
                                             )
                                       )
                     ) );
```

Comment: You answered your own question already: write a function with the variable query argument as a parameter. So... what's your question?

Comment: Or, to reduce queries, you could just grab all of the terms at once and sort them after they're retrieved.

Comment: Problem is I do not know how to write that function.

Comment: Your question may be [off-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for pertaining specifically to PHP. We also ask that questions display research effort - take a look over the "[ask]" page in the [help]. You can find your answer by reviewing [PHP's documentation on user-defined functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php), or Googling "PHP function" should bring up a number of tutorials.

Comment: Sorry for that but I always research before asking here. Waiting for answers while I can find something really quick is not what I like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on the answer by Global:

Paste this into your theme's functions.php:

```
function get_stations_query( $terms ) {
    //create new query object
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
                    'post_type'      => 'stations',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'orderby' => 'title',
                    'order' => 'ASC',
                    'tax_query' => array(
                                     array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'genres',
                                        'field' => 'name',
                                        'terms' => $terms
                                         )
                                     )
                 ) );
    return $query; //return the object
}
```

Then in your template files you can use:

```
$query = get_stations_query('pop');
```

Comment: Thank you. I did something like this already and it works. It does not require `return $query;` and I call it like `<php? get_stations_query('pop'); ?>`. Rest of the code is like yours. Is there anything wrong with this even though it works?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new function, put all the code in it and replace 'pop' with $genre. Then call it like this:

```
get_stations_query( $genre );
```

the return of your function should be

```
return $query;
```

Comment: To clarify, you call it like: 
get_stations_query( 'pop' );

Comment: Can you give an example?